# Minizinc: set enumerated set of options based on array position, as opposed to set of options for all array positions

Tags: arrays, set, constraints, minizinc

I am familiar with such approaches as

```
set of int: RANGE = 1..5;
enum OPTS = {A,B,C};
array[RANGE] of var OPTS = result;
```

but what about when I would like to specify the `OPTS` for each position in `RANGE`? Something that looks like

```
[{A,B,C},{A,B},{A,B,C,D},{B,D},{A}]
```

then generate `result[n]` so that it picks one of the available options at `n`.

I've tried with the following model but a model inconsistency is detected.

```
set of int: RANGE = 1..5;
enum OPTS = {A,B,C,D};
array[RANGE] of set of OPTS: t = [{A,B,C},{A,B},{A,B,C,D},{B,D},{A}];
array[RANGE] of var OPTS: result;
constraint forall(i in RANGE)(
  forall(j in t[i])(
    result[i] = j
  )
);

output [show(result)]
```

with a possible result being `[B,A,B,D,A]` - the last position `result[5]` cannot be anything other than `A`.

I try to use the Minizinc manuals but I cannot decipher how to use examples within the specifications eg https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.4.3/en/spec.html#set-operations, which presuppose other knowledge (e.g. how to interpret the syntax) that I could spend countless hours trying to hunt down an explanation for on my level, since searching this stuff seems to be really unfruitful.

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to tell something about this since you don't mention exactly what problem you try to solve. What solution do you expect?

Comment: Thanks, I've added a line after my model.

Comment: I've updated my answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can use `set of OPTS` to construct the array of `OPTS`, here called `t` (you cannot call it `output` since it's a reserved word). Note that as you presented the problem, it's not a `var` but a constant array so you don't need the `var` keyword when you construct the array.

```
set of int: RANGE = 1..5;
enum OPTS = {A,B,C,D};
array[RANGE] of set of OPTS: t = [{A,B,C},{A,B},{A,B,C,D},{B,D},{A}];
```

**Update**

Here's a model for the updated question. The trick here is that `t[i]` defines the valid domain of `result[i]`, and you can simply use `in` for this.

```
set of int: RANGE = 1..5;
enum OPTS = {A,B,C,D};
array[RANGE] of set of OPTS: t = [{A,B,C},{A,B},{A,B,C,D},{B,D},{A}];
array[RANGE] of var OPTS: result;

constraint 
  forall(i in RANGE) (
     % ensure that result[i] only takes the values in t[i]
     result[i] in t[i]
  )
;

output [show(result)]
```

There are 48 solutions to this problem, such as:

```
[A, A, A, B, A]
----------
[B, A, A, B, A]
----------
[C, A, A, B, A]
----------
[A, B, A, B, A]
----------
[B, B, A, B, A]
----------
[C, B, A, B, A]
----------
[A, A, B, B, A]
----------
...
```

Comment: I'm afraid I've had to edit my question since yes, your answer did answer it, but it wasn't actually what I was aiming for. I hope now it's clearer?

Comment: Perfect! Another little element I've learnt and been given an example of  - using `in` outside of a `forall()` or `sum()`, etc statement. Perfectly logical :)